# err_unknown_url_scheme WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` app that contain a wordpress site, built with elementor pro. I use a **button** that will allow the user to call or to navigate to an adress via waze. The issue is that it keeps giving me the

> **err_unknown_url_scheme**

Few fixes that did't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://perfectskin.co.il/app/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the WAZE app installed? It should register the URL schema that is currently unknown to your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add call permission to manifest file.

```
 "android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```